# Adobe replaces my fonts with generic Adobe fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-reader, microsoft-publisher

I put together a document in Microsoft Publisher and used the font Tittilium.

I clicked `Save As` and selected `Save As PDF` from the list. The problem is that the rendered PDF has the wrong fonts in place of Tuttilium.

How to I maintain the original fonts in the document?

THis is a screenshot from the Document Properties in Adobe Reader showing the fonts that should be there, and their generic replacement fonts.

[image: Adobe PDF replaced fonts]

Answer (score 0):

With the document open in Publisher, try printing to PDF instead of saving to PDF.

Acrobat allows you to save Optimized PDFs with the fonts embedded in the file. Publisher's PDF optimization settings are further explained here: [How to control the way Publisher files save as PDF](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661393)